# How to create instance variable and use inside the class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

How to create an instance variable  from the below list which contains a dictionary key called price and i am trying to retrieve the price list of all the books using a class called Library

1 ) Here is the list of books and their details

```
data = { "books" : [ { "number_of_pages" : 849,
        "price" : 13.550000000000001,
        "publish_date" : 2011,
        "subjects" : [ "Time travel",
            "Assassination"
          ],
        "title" : "11/22/63"
      },
      { "number_of_pages" : 732,
        "price" : 7.9900000000000002,
        "publish_date" : 1999,
        "subjects" : [ "Authors",
            "Custody of children",
            "Grandfathers",
            "Haunted houses",
            "Novelists",
            "Trials (Custody of children)",
            "Widowers",
            "Widows",
            "Writer's block"
          ],
        "title" : "Bag of bones"
      },]}
```

2 ) I created a class called Library which will unpack the list and store the variables

```
class Library:
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)
            #print(k,v)
        if 'price' in v[0:][1]:
              for c in v[0:][1].items():
                  if 'price' in c:
                    self.price=c['price']
               
        
    def price_book(self):
         return self.price
        
    def __float__(self):
        return self.price
 

Libra = Library(**data)
Price=Libra.price_book()
print(Price)
```

While trying to return using the instances its retuning the error for setting the variable for price ?

How to set the instance variable and retrieve list of prices in library ?

Regards

**Update 1:**

self.price=c['price']

**TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str**

**Update 2 :**

```
class Library:
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
                setattr(self, k, v)

        self.price = []
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            for i in range(len(v)):
                self.price.append(v[i]['price'])
        
    def price_book(self):
         return self.price
         
    def discount_book(self):
         self.price=self.price
         return  list(map((lambda x: x -2), self.price))
        
    def __float__(self):
        return self.price
        
Libra = Library(**data)
Price=Libra.price_book()
Pri=Libra.discount_book()
print(Price)
print(Pri)
```

Comment: You're making us guess what and where the error is.  Edit your question to include the full error message.

Comment: you *optionally* sets `price` attribute on `self` *but always* read it in `price_book` method. Your code may causing  AttributeError

Comment: @JohnGordon , updated

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan , yes, i want to set  it correctly,but running out of options

Comment: `v[0:][1]` is the same as `v[1]`, btw.

Comment: How could a `Library` class possibly have a `price_book()` method with no extra parameters?  Which book in the library do you expect it to return the price of?

Comment: @jasonharper , all of them,

Comment: In your loop, `c` is a dict item which is more like a tuple than a dict. It does not allow key access!

Comment: @schwobaseggl , corrected

Comment: @schwobaseggl , yes .  how to handle it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just having trouble seeing where you are hung up, if it's retrieving the prices or setting them to the instance.

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):

    for k, v in kwarg.items():
        setattr(self, k, v)

    self.price = []
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        for i in range(len(v)):
            self.price.append(v[i]['price'])
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/AtBS$ python3.7 comphren.py 
> [13.55, 7.99]
> ```

**Suggestion by Request**

One thing I would I didn't do because I'm unsure I think the use of `data` creates unneeded nesting that unless you are going to have `books` and say `movies` otherwise you could just call this whole thing `books` and remove one level of nesting. Also this method logs duplicates, which I worked around using `set` but you could avoid appending duplicates with more code, didn't want to do too much because still unsure of entire task.

But if the goal was just to create these lists of each piece of data this code will work:

```
pages = []
publish_dates = []
subjects = []
titles = []
prices = []

for v in data.values():
    for i in range(len(v)):
       for w, x in v[i].items():
            pages.append(v[i]['number_of_pages'])
            publish_dates.append(v[i]['publish_date'])
            titles.append(v[i]['title'])
            prices.append(v[i]['price'])
            for a in v[i]['subjects']:
                subjects.append(a)

print(f"Pages: {set(pages)}\nPublish Dates: {set(publish_dates)}\n" \
      f"Subjects: {set(subjects)}\nTitles:{set(titles)}\n" \
      f"Prices: {set(prices)}")
```

**Output**

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/AtBS$ python3.7 comphren.py 
> Pages: {849, 732}
> Publish Dates: {2011, 1999}
> Subjects: {'Time travel', 'Widows', 'Authors', 'Widowers',
> 'Assassination', 'Haunted houses', 'Grandfathers', "Writer's block",
> 'Novelists', 'Trials (Custody of children)', 'Custody of children'}
> Titles:{'11/22/63', 'Bag of bones'}
> Prices: {13.55, 7.99}
> ```

Comment: Yes, I followed this and updated in 2 , is it the right way to do it

Comment: Glad to assist!

Comment: Here, i need to unpack each keys and it may end up as a long coding.less pythonic i would say

Comment: What is the next goal of your project? What keys do you want to unpack and what do you want to do with them?

Comment: number of pages,is there any  way to do this without creating en empty list ?

Comment: Okay I think I'm catching on , are you going to make a list of every `key`'s `value`'s how you did with price? That can be done, yes but I'm curious are you not concerned with the association to the book, or you just interested in retrieving all of the values, that was a question I was going to raise with `price`

Comment: Last quesiton, is the use of classes required? After that I'll go through and do this over how I would approach it

Comment: i dont know if its a good way to do it with classes or without classes .

Comment: Take a look, not sure if that was your goal but from our conversation that is what I put together

Answer (score 1):

```
if 'price' in v[0:][1]:
    for c in v[0:][1].items():
        if 'price' in c:
            self.price=c['price']
```

The `items()` method of a dictionary returns key-value pairs as tuples.

Therefore `c` is a tuple such as `('price', 7.99)`.

Tuples are indexed by integers, not strings.

You probably want `self.price = c[1]` instead.

Comment: This method returns the last   item price

Comment: @Karamzov  I assume this is intentional.  `self.price` clearly has no capability to store multiple items.  Also, the above code is clearly **not** indented underneath the kwargs loop in the OP.

Comment: How about creating a called self.price list and storing all the values there

Comment: @Karamzov That might be better, but I'm just using the code that was in the question.